# Angular JS Directive for bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am looking for the angular directive for bootstrap-datepicker h[ttps://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/](http://ttps://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

I tried finding it but couldn't get success with that.

Does anyone know the angular directive of the plugin I mentioned?

Comment: I didnt find anything. If there is no angular native directive, you can either wrap the jquery version around a directive, or rewrite it by yourself.

Comment: Datepicker from ui-bootstrap: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: @TobiasTimm thanks for your feedback. I should go for making my own custom directive then.